# Can't send push to android using GCM

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

Sorry for my english. I have spent 2 days but I can't send push messages to android. I use google cloud message. For example in gcm I create a new project and I have an id:

[image]

Then I enabled gcm and added the server key

[image]

I have code like this:

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alexy.gcmclient">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="com.hmkcode.android.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.hmkcode.android.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.hmkcode.android.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".GcmMessageHandler"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
  </application>


</manifest>
```

**GcmBroadcastReceiver**

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.e("GcmBroadcastReceiver", "GcmBroadcastReceiver");
        // Explicitly specify that GcmMessageHandler will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmMessageHandler.class.getName());

        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

**GcmMessageHandler**

```
public class GcmMessageHandler extends IntentService {

    String mes;
    private Handler handler;
    public GcmMessageHandler() {
        super("GcmMessageHandler");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        handler = new Handler();
        Log.e("GcmMessageHandler", "GcmMessageHandler");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        Log.e("message", messageType);
    }
```

**Main**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button btnRegId, unregister;
    EditText etRegId;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    String regid;
    String PROJECT_NUMBER = "308****";

    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        unregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.unregister);
        btnRegId = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetRegId);
        etRegId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRegId);

        btnRegId.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    public void getRegId(){
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";

                try {

                    InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    String token = instanceID.getToken(PROJECT_NUMBER,
                            GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

                    msg = token;
                    //apiKey = msg;
                    GcmPubSub.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).subscribe(token, "/topics/users", null);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                }



                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                etRegId.setText(msg + "\n");
                Log.e("key", msg);

            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }

   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getRegId();
    }

}
```

I use [service](http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/) and tried to send some push messages to the device. In service it says Success. But the push in android is not coming (I have no output in the log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your app package name must be **com.example.alexy.gcmclient** or replace the package name build.gradle

```
defaultConfig 
        applicationId "com.yourpackge"
```

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.alexy.gcmclient.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="com.example.alexy.gcmclient.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />



   <receiver android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
              <intent-filter>
                    <action       android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <category android:name="com.example.alexy.gcmclient" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

The package names for C2D_MESSAGE are wrong, change them to your package name. Also, make sure you have the configuration file near the build.gradle of your app directory. Edit: go through all of the manifest and change wherever you see hmk to your package name. Your package name should be com.example.alexy.gcmclient as per your manifest.